# Are these random variables independent? (noise samples in the discretization of an SDE)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a linear stochastic differential equation:
$$
dx = Axdt+dv
$$
for some constant matrix $A$. Moreover $x(t_0)$ is normally distributed with  mean $m_0$ and covariance $P_0$. $v(t)$ is a Wiener process with incremental covariance $Qdt$. If I have a sequence of instants $t_0<t_1<t_2<\dots$ with $t_{k+1}-t_{k}=h$, it is known that one can write
$$
x(t_{k+1}) = \exp(Ah)x(t_k) + v_k
$$
where $v_k$ is normally distributed with zero mean and covariance
$$
Q_h = \int_0^h\exp(Ah)Q\exp(A^Th)dt
$$

**My question is**: are the random variables $v_1,v_2,\dots$ independent from each other?

**EDIT** Another way to write $v_k$ is as
$$
v_k = \int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}}\exp(A(t_{k+1}-\tau))dv(\tau)
$$
following equation (19) [here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1474667015353015?token=30D378FCD720327B6D451A716005609F352B2D6E7B9F2FD24C6F9CB257DDBA7B6A6D1EB1B2B022EE11BF146DB0648202&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210714105101).

Comment: Is that not implied in "Wiener process"? Or rather, that they are not independent, rather that instead that increments are independent.

Comment: Can you elaborate? do you mean they are not independent? The confusion I have is that $v_k$ are not the samples of the Wiener process $v(t)$ directly, but are the left over you get when plugging in the solution to the SDE to get a transition rule for the samples of $x(t_{k})$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh, I understand what you where asking now. A Wiener process has independent incrementes.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. By the new formula, the $v_k$ are composed of increments that are independent for different $k$.

Comment: Ah! I see it now... Intuitively, the increments $dv$ in interval are all different for each interval, right? Do you think there is a more formal way to check this? Or is this the most "formal" we can get? Thanks anyway!